# CrudRepository.findOne(null) returning Null

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I'm using `CrudRepositroy.findOne` method, in one if the case, I'm getting null into `findOne` method.
as per the `findOne` implementation I should get a `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException`, but I'm getting `null` as a result for `findOne` method. Not sure why.

Here is the code:

```
public interface RepositoryClass extends CrudRepository<MyBean, String> {  
}

MyBean {
    String var1;
    String var2;
}

MyServiceClass {
    String test = repositoryClass.findOne(bean.var1);
}
```

in My Service class bean.var1 I'm passing `null`,

Expected: Exception,
Actual : I'm getting "null"

any thoughts.

Comment: It seems you are using an extremely outdated version of Spring Data. You might consider updating to a recent version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you passing argument is not null and given id not exist in DB so you are getting null. if passing argument is null then you will get **IllegalArgumentException**.

Thanks